# В чем отличие рекурсивного процесса от итеративного в Си

Tags: c, циклы

В чем отличие по затрачиваемой памяти, времени? Какой процесс лучше использовать(например поиск числа фибоначчи)

Comment: Итеративный всегда лучше

Comment: но не всегда проще. Если рекурсия не слишком глубокая - может, и не имеет смысла корячитьмся и делать итеративный код. Теми более что хвостовую рекурсию обычно оптимизатор сам в сорстоянии развернуть в итерацию.

Comment: @Mikhailo, с тем, что рекурсивные по своей сути алгоритмы (обход дерева или разбор грамматики (по сути построение дерева) или quicksort) проще запрограммировать в виде рекурсивоной программы никто не спорит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема с рекурсией в том, что программно невозможно контролировать аппаратный стек. И при достаточно глубоком погружении происходит креш программы. Поэтому рекомендуется рекурсию в реальных (не учебных) программах не использовать, а использовать банальные циклы и стековые структуры данных. Кроме того, что стековые структуры данных можно программно контролировать, еще обычно размер кучи гораздо больше, чем размер аппаратного стека. Соответственно, кучи хватит на большее количество циклов.

UPD1:

> программно невозможно контролировать аппаратный стек

Тут я на досуге подумал над этими словами. По идее, ОС **может** предоставлять приложению средства для контроля аппаратного стека приложения. А транслятор **может**  предоставлять приложению размер стекового кадра данной функции. И тогда перед каждой итерацией можно будет проверять, сколько стека осталось. И, таким образом, избежать затирания стека и креша программы. Но вряд-ли такие средства сейчас есть в реально используемых ОС и трансляторах.